Concatenating netcdf and hdf5 files
I have two data files in two formats, one is netcdf, the other is hdf5. I wish to combine them and export the combined data as hdf5. My current solution includes converting each to a python dictionary and them combining the dictionaries and converting the combined dictionary to hdf5. Is there a better solution for this?

Do you mean that they have differently named datasets and you just want the datasets from both? Or do you need to concatenate datasets with equal names?

differently named datasets with different data, yes.

"better solution" depends on what you want to improve. :-) I would not convert datasets to dictionaries. You can easily copy HDF5 datasets with the h5py copy() method. Ref: h5py Group Copy. I suggest reading NetCDF data into NumPy arrays, then creating the H5 datasets directly from them (using the data= keyword). Much cleaner and easier than converting data to/from dictionaries (IMHO).

# open the HDF5 file
with h5py.File(hdf5_path, 'r+') as hdf:  # 'r+' mode allows overwrite existing file
    # open the NetCDF file
    ncdf_file = Dataset(self.CDF_path, 'r')
    # create a new group for NetCDF data within HDF5 file
    ncdf_group = hdf.create_group(f'Advanced_ASTRA/Astra_output')

    # loop over each variable in the NetCDF file
    for var in ncdf_file.variables:
        # create a new group for each variable
        var_group = ncdf_group.create_group(var)
        # save data, units, and long_name as datasets within this group
        var_group.create_dataset('data', data=ncdf_file.variables[var][:])
        var_group.create_dataset('units', data=str(ncdf_file.variables[var].units))
        var_group.create_dataset('long_name', data=str(ncdf_file.variables[var].long_name))

    ncdf_file.close()


If you are using python already, the easiest way would be to use Xarray. Xarray can read both NetCDF and HDF5 into xarray datasets, and then you can combine into a single dataset and then write to netcdf4 (which is HDF5 under the hood), like:
import xarray as xr
import h5netcdf

ds1 = xr.open_dataset("/path/to/my/file.h5")
ds2 = xr.open_dataset("/path/to/my/file.nc")

ds = xr.concat([ds1, ds2])

ds.to_netcdf('combined.nc')

Of course you might need to do a bit of manipulation of the datasets ds1 and ds2 to make sure the variables and dimensions match so they can be concatenated.
